# Founder of Project disappeared. Can wallet OWNER, of Royalties accumulating, change WALLET on ETHERSCAN to another received royalties?

Tags: contract-development, etherscan, royalties

It is a frustrating situation that the community was left behind. Project has potential so we want to keep the project moving. We have zero contact with Founder.
Here is the issue:

1. Founder left the project but only left Discord login details, and Twitter login details. No OpenSea login details.
2. Founder switched royalties over to Member #1's wallet before disappearing. Now Member #1 does not want royalties in her wallet.

Is there a way, through Member #1's ETHERSCAN, to change Royalties to be directed to Member #2's wallet?

I appreciate the help.

-Chorey

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the project?

Comment: The project was in shambles before I took lead on it. We are the SpaceBoysNFT.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to move royalties unfortunately, unless you have access to the original smart contract. There are however two alternatives I can think of:

1. If the royalties are ERC20's with approve functionality, the user receiving the royalties can approve another user or smart contract to use/take their tokens. It would require a manual withdrawal each time the royalties are taken though, so this option is little better than just handing over the wallet directly.
2. You could create a [wrapper NFT](https://metadrop.com/drops/wrapped-penguins). The Pudgy Penguins group was more or less rugged so they created a wrapper NFT. In order to make this work, holders of the original NFT have to interact with the new wrapping contract to wrap their NFT. Proceeds/control of the contract go to whoever created that wrapping contract. Downside of this is that each NFT holder has to interact directly with that wrapping contract--expensive and far from automatic.

Comment: If the original smart contract is on OpenSea, then we do not. 

1. We would have to verify the functionality of the ERC20. Currently, we are having to ask the Royalties holder to send us the ETH monthly, its a drag. Another option we explored WAS handing over the ledger lol

2. This crossed my mind, we would lose the Original Royalties, but now the wrapped NFT would have a brand new contract?

Comment: For 2. yeah the original royalties would still be going to the same place, but the royalties of anyone who wrapped their NFT would be going to the new contract and its designated royalty receivers. I think it's the best long-term solution because it gives back all the power to the community.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. This gives us more confidence to move forward. If you are free and have a wallet, please contact me on twitter @spaceboyChorizo. I would like gift you something for your time.

Comment: Sent! Good luck, I'm willing to help out more if possible.

Comment: I am @romanticore3 btw.